# Run background task inside Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I was writing an automatic test framework with Jest. For this, I need to run some background tasks under certain intervals. In summary, this is like polling. Let's give an example with a pseudo code.

```
test('Some potato poteto test', () => {
    jest.setTimeout(12000000); // 20 min

    const intervalPeriod = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 min

    let retry = 0;

    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("I am doing my 5 minutes check");
      
      // my custom logic goes here

      retry++;
  
      if(retry === MAX_RETRY) { // this will be always hit
        clearInterval(intervalId)
      }
    }, intervalPeriod);
});
```

So, in every 5 mins, I'll make a network call, do some of my custom logic. Now, the problem is while running this, the test finished but `jest` can't terminate.

By 'test-finished' I meant, test suite ran, but the code inside the `setInterval` does not get executed right then.

My question is, does this happen because `setInterval` does not run immediately in the event-loop and is `jest` not configured to run a `setInterval`?

Please note that I don't want to mock the `setInterval` and also I don't want to use any fake timer.

Therefore, is it possible to achieve this with `Jest`?

I also tried the same thing with the `cron` library for node but it is the same issue. `Jest` does not execute the code and finish executing then halted because those `setInterval/cron` are still running in the background.

Is there a way to run those tasks inside Jest? I mean is there a way to run those jobs and when they are done then terminate Jest?

Comment: useFakeTimers is the way to go... but if you really really dont want to... theres the flag `--maxWorkers` that spans workers based on the cores of your machine... this test alone would consume a whole core for 5 minutes... so... maybe you could make this test as something separate? (as in only run when you do something like test:thatonethattakes5min)

Answer (score 0):

That's intended, Jest execute all the test instructions and quit the test.

For jest to wait for a computation, you need to use Promises and its async mode.

Doc for Jest async mode: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Learn more about Promises here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

And async/await syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

This is a naive way for doing it:

```
const MAX_RETRY = 3;
const INTERVAL_PERIOD = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 min
const SAFETY_TIME = INTERVAL_PERIOD;
const TEST_TIMEOUT = (1 + MAX_RETRY) * INTERVAL_PERIOD + SAFETY_TIME; 

test('Some potato poteto test', async () => {
    let retry = 0;
    let success = false;
    function yourLogicFunction(): boolean {
        const resultOfYourLogicFunction = retry === MAX_RETRY; // because retry is used in this condition I store the result before changing it
        console.log(`this is my attempt number ${retry}`);
        retry++;
        return resultOfYourLogicFunction;
    }
    function mockRequest(resolve: (value: unknown) => void): void {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(yourLogicFunction()), INTERVAL_PERIOD);
    }
    while (!success && retry <= MAX_RETRY) {
        success = await new Promise(mockRequest) as boolean;
    }
}, TEST_TIMEOUT);
```

The third parameter of test is its timeout.